# iPhone facebook connection is not working with existing native facebook app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an iPhone app using facebook connection using FBConnect from github code.

It worked fine in the simulator, however when I installed it in the device with existing facebook app from facebook it didn't work. It opens the existing facebook app instead of returning to my own app.

How to avoid this kind of conflict using FBConnect for facebook connection with existing facebook app?

FYI, facebook app screen says "You have already authorized MagLetters. Press "Okay" to continue." however when I click "Okay" it will bring me facebook app's default page not to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the following:

- Are you running the latest Facebook App?
- Did you setup the URL Schemes in your plist file?
- Are you overriding the application:handleOpenURL: method?